# Why devExpress gives a binding error for single documents when select two page scrolling option?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, devexpress

just trying to view a pdf using DevExpress library and when it comes to single-page document and I was trying to apply the option of Two Page Scrolling. Then it gives a binding error with saying below description. Could anyone please help me to resolve this problem?

> 2021-02-01 07:55:50,551 1 Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; {0}='{1}' BindingExpression:Path=VerticalOffset; DataItem='DXScrollViewer' (Name='PART_ScrollViewer'); target element is 'ScrollBar' (Name='PART_VerticalScrollBar'); target property is 'Value' (type 'Double')>

[This image will describe how I tried to use this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIbkA.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the Type of the value that you bound is not the expected. In such cases, it is possible that a Converter might help. Please check [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert?view=net-5.0) on the official documentation of Microsoft for more information.

PS: If you have a license for DevExpress, you can always send a Support Ticket to the [DevExpress Support Team](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/). I already consulted them multiple times and they were always happy to help. Sometimes, it is very specific for DevExpress and with general WPF knowledge you cannot find the problem.